# Any good tutorial on SARIMAX model time series?

Tags: time-series, python, arima, references

I know it's kind of a naive question, but somehow I am unable to find a good tutorial on the SARIMAX time series model. The online content is usually an API implementation that is more of a black-box.

However, since I am in a learning stage, I wish to get a feel of the mathematics that goes on at the backend.

Any help in this direction will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not specifically aimed at the Python implementation, but I recommend [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* (2nd ed.) by Athanasopoulos & Hyndman](https://otexts.org/fpp2/), which is free and online, for the SARIMA aspects. Note that different implementations follow different conventions, in particular about the signs for the MA part - these may be flipped.

For the X part, I recommend [Rob Hyndman's blog post on "The ARIMAX Model Muddle"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/).